# Catching errors from React Router action in Formik

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom, formik

I wrote an app with React-Router actions and loaders, and later I've changed react Form to a Formik form, which sends data using `useSubmit` hook. Is there any way to catch errors from action function and display them as Formik errors (using Formik helpers like `setErrors` function)? For now, I'm displaying errors from submitting separately.

My Login component:

```
export const Login = () => {
  const data = useActionData<typeof action>()
  return (
    ...
    <LoginForm data={data} />
  )
}
```

LoginForm (fragment):

```
const LoginForm = (props: { data: ReturnType<typeof useActionData<typeof action>> }) => {
    const submit = useSubmit()
return (
        <Formik
            initialValues={initialValues}
            validationSchema={validationSchema}
            onSubmit={(values) => submit(values, { method: "post" })}
        >
            {() => {
                return (
                    < Form
                        className='flex flex-col items-center max-w-sm gap-4 ' >
                        <div className='text-center'>

                            <Field
                                type="email"
                                name="email"
                                required
                                placeholder='Email adress'
                                className='px-3 py-1 mb-1'
                            />
                            <ErrorMessage name="email" component="div" className="text-sm text-red-500" />
                            {(typeof props.data === 'object' && props?.data?.error === 'auth/user-not-found') && <p className="text-sm text-red-500">Incorrect email</p>}
                        </div>
```

action.tsx:

```
export async function action({ request }: ActionFunctionArgs) {
    const formData = await request.formData();
    const email = String(formData.get('email'));
    const password = String(formData.get('password'));

    try {
        const data = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
        localStorage.setItem('loggedUser', JSON.stringify(data.user.uid))
        return redirect('/projects')
    } catch (error) {
        if (error instanceof Error) return { error: error.code }
        return String(error)
    }
}
```

I've tried to:

1. use props in `onSubmit` function, with try and catch but it didn't work (`props.data` before submitting are undefined, and in catch block no errors appear)
2. pass `setErrors` function to submit function, but it takes only values and options as arguments

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`useRouteError`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-route-error) to access errors returned by route loaders and action. You'll need to also render your routed component as the route's `errorElement` as well.

Example:

```
<Route
  path: "/login",
  action: loginAction,
  errorElement: <Login />,
  element: <Login />
/>
```

or

```
{
  path: "/login",
  action: loginAction,
  errorElement: <Login />,
  element: <Login />
}
```

Update `Login` to use the `useRouteError` and conditionally render any errors returned from the route.

```
import { useRouteError, useSubmit } from 'react-router-dom';
...

const LoginForm = (
  props: {
    data: ReturnType<typeof useActionData<typeof action>>
  }
) => {
  const submit = useSubmit();
  const error = useRouteError(); // <-- access error

  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={initialValues}
      validationSchema={validationSchema}
      onSubmit={(values) => submit(values, { method: "post" })}
    >
      {() => {
        return (
          <Form className='flex flex-col items-center max-w-sm gap-4 '>
            {error && /* error UI */} // <-- conditionally render error

            ...
          </Form>
        );
      }
    </Formik>
  );
}
```